# Openlayers zoomToExtent pause until image is retrieved

Tags: openlayers-2

Problem:

1. layer transition effect: resize
2. Do programmatic map.zoomToExtent() to somewhere OUTSIDE of current wms map bounds
3. OpenLayers setCenters to target bounds and zooms in.
4. While new wms image is being downloaded, OpenLayers displays 'enlarged' map
5. Once wms image is loaded, it's transitioned into map viewport

Is there a way to 'prevent' OpenLayers from set-centering at #3 until wms image is downloaded ?

What I want:

1. as above
2. as above
3. as above
4. OpenLayers doesn't setCenter nor zoom-in (or just doesn't update map)
5. if new WMS image is loaded, then update map.

Answer (score 1):

you can check out my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/25876/3071) which can give u some aspect about what u want.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: ok thanks, i'll modify my code to register for loaded event and see if i can fix the problem.

Comment: This doesn't help, as OpenLayers move the center to new location, and THEN request new tile based on new extent. Can we request new image for an extent without moving the map ?

Comment: new followup question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28724/can-we-request-new-openlayer-wms-image-for-an-extent-without-moving-the-map